# Where is the Qt binary file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, binaryfiles

I'm on Manjaro based on Arch Linux.
I searched everywhere, and I cannot seem to find that binary file.
Searched /usr/lib/qt, used find and which commands, etc.
The only might-be relevant thing I found is in /usr/lib/qt6/bin/, I found a binary file called "qt-cmake". But I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm looking for.

My final goal is to install the latest release version of Qt Creator on GitHub, and installation needs to know the paths of two binary files :

1. Qt
2. Llfw

Installation guide precisely says "These instructions assume that Ninja is installed and in the PATH, Qt Creator sources are located at /path/to/qtcreator_sources, Qt is installed in /path/to/Qt, and LLVM is installed in /path/to/llvm."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Qt binary file" per se. Qt is a framework, delivered as a (large) group of libraries and header files.

The Qt installer should provide you with everything you need. I'm not sure this link will work for you, but...
[Qt Installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4)

As an aside, Qt Creator is an IDE for building and testing Qt-based applications. It isn't clear to me why you'd need the sources for that.

Comment: I need sources because I program stuff with Qt Creator, and I need to build Qt Creator from sources. I'm 100% sure I did no get confused with Qt/Qt Creator writing my question. Anyways, thx for helping.

Comment: OK. Did you install the Qt libraries using the installer I linked?

Comment: Yes I did. I found the binaries, and they were the same as in /usr/lib/qt6/bin. Now I have to install llvm and since they didn't make a compiled version of the package for Arch, I have to compile it, and my PC is dying right now. Thank you for the help, once again.